# The proof of Atiyah proposition 3.11 (3) and (4)

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am reading Atiyah's Introduction to commutative algebra. I have difficulty proving proposition 3.11 (3)   and (4). The following is my confusion.

(3) For the "$\mathfrak{a}$ is contracted" $\Longrightarrow$ "$s\in S, x\not\in\mathfrak{a}\Longrightarrow sx\not\in\mathfrak{a}$" side, I have worked out this:

$\mathfrak{a}$ is contracted $\Longrightarrow$ $\mathfrak{a}^{ec}\subseteq \mathfrak{a}$ Since $\mathfrak{a}^e=\mathfrak{a}/S$ (by (1)), we can infer that $\forall a\in\mathfrak{a},s\in S$ $\exists x\in \mathfrak{a}$ s.t. $f(x)=a/s$, i.e. $x/1=a/s$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\exists t\in S$ s.t. $xst=at$. Now if $s\in S$ and $sx\in\mathfrak{a}$, then $\exists a\in\mathfrak{a}$ and $t\in S$ s.t. $sxt=sat$. But why this implies $x\in \mathfrak{a}$?

(4) The writer said that $S^{-1}A/S^{-1}\mathfrak{p}$ and $\bar{S}^{-1}(A/\mathfrak{p})$ are isomorphic. To prove this, I wanted to construct a ring homomorphism $f:S^{-1}A\rightarrow \bar{S}^{-1}(A/\mathfrak{p})$, $a/s\mapsto (a/1)/(s/1)$, and then prove that its kernel is $S^{-1}\mathfrak{p}$. I have proved that this mapping is well-defined, and $x\in\ker f\Longrightarrow x\in S^{-1}\mathfrak{p}$   . But how to prove that $x\in S^{-1}\mathfrak{p}\Longrightarrow x\in\ker f$?

---

### Edit: the detailed answer to my question

edit: Thanks to raisinsec. Now I can solve my problem. I have written it in detail.

(3) $\Longrightarrow$: $sx\in\mathfrak{a}\Rightarrow sx/1\in S^{-1}\mathfrak{a}\Rightarrow f(x)=x/1=1/s\cdot sx/1\in S^{-1}\mathfrak{a}\Rightarrow x\in f^{-1}(S^{-1}\mathfrak{a})=\mathfrak{a}$ since $\mathfrak{a}$ is contracted.

(4) For $S^{-1}A/S^{-1}\mathfrak{p}$ and $\bar{S}^{-1}(A/\mathfrak{p})$ are isomorphic, consider $\psi$: $a/s\mapsto(a+p)/(s+p)$. (Note that $A/\mathfrak{p}$ is the quotient ring!) We first check that it is well-defined. If $a_1/s_1=a_2/s_2$ then $\exists t\in S$ s.t. $a_1s_2t=a_2s_1t$. Since $(a_1+\mathfrak{p})/(s_1+\mathfrak{p})=(a_2+\mathfrak{p})/s_2+\mathfrak{p}\Longleftrightarrow \exists t\in S$ s.t. $(a_1s_2-a_2s_1+\mathfrak{p})(t+\mathfrak{p})=0\Longleftrightarrow a_1s_2t-a_2s_1t\in\mathfrak{p}$ we conclude $\psi$ well-defined. And it is not hard to show $\psi $ a homomorphism. Now we determine $\ker\psi$. If $\psi(a/s)=0$ i.e. $(a+\mathfrak{p})/(s+\mathfrak{p})=0$ then $\exists t\in S$ s.t. $(a+\mathfrak{p})(t+\mathfrak{p})=0\Longleftrightarrow at+\mathfrak{p}=0\Longleftrightarrow at\in\mathfrak{p}$. If $a\in\mathfrak{p}$ then we simply take $t=1$ and $a1=a\in S$. Conversely if $at_0\in\mathfrak{p}$ for $t_0\in S$, we infer from $\mathfrak{p}$ prime and $S\cap \mathfrak{p}=\emptyset$ that $a\in \mathfrak{p}$

Comment: Not experimented in answering so take caution with what I say, but maybe for 3) we have that $sx\in \mathfrak a\implies \frac{sx}{1}\in \mathfrak a/S \implies \frac{x}{1}\in  \mathfrak a/S$ and now we use the fact that $\mathfrak a$ is contracted to get $x\in \mathfrak a$

Comment: For 4) I don't understand your map, I don't think element of $\overline{S}$ or $(A/\mathfrak p)$ can be written as quotients, they are equivalence classes. Try to rewrite your map with $a/s\mapsto(a+p)/(s+p)$ and check if it's well defined maybe.

Comment: @raisinsec   Well, for (3), I think $x/1\in\mathfrak{a}/S$ implies $\exists s, t\in S$ and $a\in\mathfrak{a}$ s.t. $at=sxt$, and I still get stuck why this imolies $x\in\mathfrak{a}$. For (4), the $(a/1)$ and $(s/1)$ are equivalence classes, and they are members of $A/\mathfrak{a}$ and $\bar{S}$ respectively.

Comment: For 3) I meant : $\frac{x}{1}\in \mathfrak a/S\implies \exists a\in \mathfrak a$ such that $\frac{a}{1}=\frac{x}{1}$ so $\frac{x}{1}\in f(\mathfrak a)$. Now we have that $x\in f^{-1}(\{ \frac{x}{1} \})\subseteq f^{-1}(\mathfrak a/S)\subseteq \mathfrak a$ since it's contracted. For 4) I never saw that but as long as we speak of the same thing. The thing is that by definition of $A/\mathfrak p$, if you take $p\in \mathfrak p$ you'll get $p/1(=p+\mathfrak p)=0/1(=0+\mathfrak p)$. So take $x=p/s\in S^{-1}\mathfrak p$, we get $x\mapsto (p/1)/(s/1)=0/(s/1)=0$.

Comment: @raisinsec Thanks. I think now I understand it. For (4) I have made a mistake. The $A/\mathfrak{p}$ is in fact the quotient ring, not the ring of fraction.

Comment: Nice for 3). Now for 4) I think you should take a look again at the definition, and you'll see then that the part you struggled with is really given by definition. That's what I wrote in my previous comment, using the correct notations in parentheses.

Comment: @raisinsec Yes, thanks a lot! I have edited my answer and added a detailed proof for other learners to have a reference also.